# Not able to run application through emulator in mac

Tags: appium, eclipse

Code:

```
public class AppDAta {
    public static URL url;
      public static DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
      public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

      //1
      @Test
      public void setupAppium() throws MalformedURLException {
        //2
        final String URL_STRING = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";
        url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        //3
        DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Nexus_4_API_27");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "3.6.0");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/uss/Desktop/untitled folder/Appium/src/main/java/Appium/ApiDemos-debug.apk");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
       // cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
        cap.setCapability("useNewWDA", false);
        //4
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(url, cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.resetApp();
      }

}
```

Getting this type of error in console:

```
FAILED: setupAppium
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in PATH. Please set the ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variables to the corect Android SDK root directory path.
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'tests-Mac-mini.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:431:f1c:51d3:566a%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in PATH. Please set the ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variables to the corect Android SDK root directory path.
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explainatory. Check your environment variables (run Terminal and use command printenv ) ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT if they are a) set and b) if they point to proper location. I

Comment: i already set, still getting error.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @masoodghz as stated in the error: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6'

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience in the qa services, it appears like required ADB paths are not completely configured on the Mac machine.

So for that, along with the ANDROID_HOME variable, 02 additional paths:

- pointing to the **'platform-tools'** and **'platforms'** folder, 
  inside the Android SDK folder also needs to be initialized in the main PATH variable.

***Providing below an instance for setting the 02 additional paths on Mac:***

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms
```